# Include content of x.php page as a block in index.php

Tags: php

I have created some comment box kind of thing in `x.php`. Looks like comment section here:

http://yepinol.com/wall/

Now I want to include it as a block in my other page index.php which has already some content

So should I copy and paste the code for that content or is there any other way so that I can directly include the content at some position in my index.php?

Comment: I think PHP has ways to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) files...

Comment: Try looking up: 'include'

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Include+content+of+x.php+page) for the same query would have given you the answer. A little bit of research always helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include it into another webpage, use the php include function:

```
<?php include("filelocation/x.php"); ?>
```

x.php will then be placed on the webpage where the code above was placed.

Comment: `<div style="left:40px top:30px">
<?php include("filelocation/x.php"); ?>
</div>` is this ok?

Comment: seems ok but where i have said "filelocation" you have to change that to the location of the file from the root OR the web location

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use code using include operator. Read about it on official PHP documentation site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php